# Android : Calling the Android Gallery with a Exif Attributes Filter

Tags: android, exif

I would like to pick photos for my app via the Android gallery, however, I only want to be able to pick ones with certain Exif Attributes e.g taken in the last x hours

Is there a way to call the Android gallery via an intent but filter what the user can see/select?

```
 intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
 android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 
 startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_RESULT);
```

Comment: No. That is not possible sadly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cursor for that

```
String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN};

String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"; 

cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        columns,
        null,    
        null,
        orderBy);
```

Comment: So this will launch the gallery intent and only show ones newer than say 24hours